# Loading image to canvas by string in processing

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, processing, loadimage

Brand new to this and thought i'd give processing a go.

How can I get an image to load to the canvas by a string input? So far I have managed to make the image load if key is pressed e.g:

```
if (key == 't' || key == 't') {
img=loadImage ("thebarleymow.jpg");
image(img,0,200);
}
}
```

What would be the process of making it load through a series of characters? 
i.e Type 'badger' img=loadImage ("badger.jpg");

Look forward to hearing back. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough code sample.
Whenever a user inputs a correct image name, the image will be loaded.
I hope this will help.

```
var target = "badger";
var inputs = [];
document.onkeydown = function (e){  
    e = e || window.event; // for InternetExplorer
    inputs.push(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
    var testStr = inputs.join("");
    if (target.substr(0,inputs.length).toUpperCase() !== testStr){
        inputs = [];
        return;
    }
    if(testStr.length === target.length){
        //console.log("you inputed image name!");
        img=loadImage (target + ".jpg");
        image(img,0,200);
    }
};
```